# get a list of all installed application on windows 7 phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

is it possible to get a list of all installed application on windows 7 phone?
Till now I didn't find any API that I can use.
I know this is possible on android , and it seams weird that you cant do it on windows windows 7 phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

There is a personal data information issue with this information being available.  i.e. You could infer/gather information about people based on the apps they have installed. Users may not want you to know what apps they have installed for personal or other reasons.

If you want to track whether a users has installed any of your other apps (maybe so you don't cross promote apps they've already installed) you will have to do this by having each app report it's usage (installation) to a central server along with the device/user id (ANID) and then determine whcih apps have been installed.

Comment: Yes, there are very good reasons why this is not possible, and this is a good example of one of the ways that Windows Phone is a far more secure platform than Android.